# Updating Multiple Rows

Tags: php

I can't seem to find this anywhere, but I'm trying to update multiple rows based off of one query. I want the IF parameter to execute to set all the characters to inactive then to run the query to set one character to active in order to make it so only one character can be selected. 
IE

```
UPDATE characters SET active='1'
WHERE name = '_POST[char_name]';
```

But I can't find out how to set it to where something along the lines of

```
    IF active='1' 
{
    UPDATE characters SET active='0'
    WHERE id= '" . $id . "';
}
```

Comment: check [IF statement in SQL procedures](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.sql.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0024349.htm)

Comment: Can you explain your question little further. the question is not much clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below will set `active` to 1 if `_name` is equal to `$_POST['char_name']` and will set `active` to 0 for other rows.

```
$query = "
    UPDATE characters 
    SET active = IF(_name = '".$_POST['char_name']."', '1', '0')
    WHERE id = '$id'
";
```

For more details, see [IF() MySQL function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if).

Comment: The biggest problem there is then I can see it hitting other accounts.

Comment: @MorganGreen, you can add WHERE condition. It is not so clear from your question what exactly is needed. Sorry if I pointed you in wrong direction.

Comment: Not so much that you pointed me in the wrong direction; more of I'm delving in a bit deeper then what I actually know what to do; Sorry if it came off rude at all; wasn't the intent.
I'm actually using the Case and so my Query is 
`code`$query=mysql_query("UPDATE characters 
          set active = case
                          when active = 1 then 0
                         end
   WHERE account= '" . $id . "'");`code` and my id variable is found by using

Comment: `code`$id = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `account` WHERE `username` = '" . $username . "'");
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($id);
   $id=$row['id'];`code` and my returned query is simply 1 when I echo the query.

Comment: Now I understand. check my updated answer, it is much shorter than answer of @Arun Killu

Comment: That sets all fields to 1 no matter what the value they were before, My end goal is that a player can only select one character so if they have Bob, Joe and Willy as their characters, their ID is 5 in the account database and it links through the characters. When they select Joe as their character it finds id 5 characters and sets Bob and Willy to 0 and sets Joe to 1. Now later they want to play on Willy. When they select Willy Joe and Bob are in id 5 and it sets them to 0 while setting Willy to 1. Hopefully that clears it up a little.

Comment: Yes, it did :) I've edited my answer, just added WHERE condition. That query will work exactly as you described.

Comment: Much Better; Thanks a ton for the help; this has been a massive headache.

Answer (score 1):

```
     update characters 
          set active = case
                          when active = 1 then '0'
                          else 1
                         end
   WHERE id= '" . $id . "';
```

Comment: Thanks; I was thinking it was a case when I got the link from Nullpointer
@NullPointer: Thanks for the link it's a massive help in future work and Thanks to Arun for the official answer to it.